# Why does a shape (3,3) matrix times a (3,) vector plus a (3,) vector make a (1,3) shape in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

My code is as follows doing the jacobi decomposition to solve a matrix

```
def iterative_solver(M, b, Vinit, kmax, epsmax):
    """
    Provides an approximation of M^{-1}b using the proposed iterative method
    ----------   
    parameters:
    M      : matrix in the equation MV = b to solve (numpy array of size N,N)
    b      : vector on the right-hand-side of the equation MV = b (numpy array of size N)
    Vinit  : initial vector of the iterative method (numpy array of size N)
    kmax   : maximum number of iterations, stops if k reaches kmax (integer)
    epsmax : tolerance on the residual, stops if eps reaches epsmax (float)
    
    returns:
    V   : resulting vector at the end of the iterations (numpy array of size N)
    eps : vector composed of the residuals eps at every iteration (numpy array of size k)
    k   : number of iterations performed before the algorithm stops (integer)
    """
    eps = np.inf
    N = len(M)
    d = list()
    for i in range(N):
        d.append(M[i,i])
    D = np.diag(d)
    R = D - M
    Dinv = np.linalg.inv(D)
    V = Vinit
    k =0
    print(f"V: {np.shape(V)} M: {np.shape(M)} b: {np.shape(b)}")
    
    
    while k <= kmax and eps >= epsmax:
        A = np.matmul((-M), V)+ b
        print(f"np.shape(A): {np.shape(A)}")
        V = V + np.matmul(Dinv,A)
        print(f"np.shape(V): {np.shape(V)}")
        #A = np.matmul(R,V)
        #V = np.matmul(Dinv, A + b)
        k += 1
        eps = np.linalg.norm(M*V.T-b)
    return V, eps, k

M = np.mat([[3,1,0],[-1, -5, 1], [0,2,4]])
b = np.array([4,-5,6]).T
Vinit = np.random.rand(3).T
kmax = 100
epsmax = 1e-10

print(f"solved: {iterative_solver(M, b, Vinit, kmax, epsmax)}")
```

However it gives me the output

V: (3,) M: (3, 3) b: (3,)
np.shape(A): (1, 3)

Which is very weird since a shape (3,3)  matrix times a (3,) vector plus a (3,)  vector make a (1,3) shape in numpy?

Comment: Why is it weird? Maybe I didn't get it, but mathematical multiplication of 3x3 matrix times 3x1 matrix will give a 3x1 matrix

Comment: It took me a while to notice this, but the problem is your use of `np.mat`.

Comment: @Lidbey in this case I get a 1x3 matrix and it isn't 3x1, that's why it's weird?

Answer (score 1):

The shape business is buried in your code, but I think this is what you are referring to:

```
V: (3,) M: (3, 3) b: (3,) 
A = np.matmul((-M), V)+ b
```

`matmul` of a (3,3) with (3,) produces a (3,).  Add a (3,) should stay (3,)

But then you change `V` with `V + np.matmul(Dinv,A)`.  You print its shape, but I don't see that.

```
In [224]: V = np.arange(3)
     ...: M = np.ones((3, 3))
     ...: b = np.ones(3)
In [225]: V, M, b
Out[225]: 
(array([0, 1, 2]),
 array([[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]]),
 array([1., 1., 1.]))
In [226]: np.matmul((-M), V) + b
Out[226]: array([-2., -2., -2.])
```

With your code:

```
In [23]: iterative_solver(M, b, Vinit, kmax, epsmax)
V: (3,) M: (3, 3) b: (3,)
np.shape(A): (1, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [23] in <module>
    iterative_solver(M, b, Vinit, kmax, epsmax)
  Input In [4] in iterative_solver
    V = V + np.matmul(Dinv, A)
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 1 is different from 3)
```

I tried:

```
In [25]: -M @ Vinit
Out[25]: matrix([[-2.66022252,  2.20102655, -2.90845177]])
```

It took me a bit to notice that this is `np.matrix`!  That by definition is 2d, hence the (1,3) shape.

If I pass a `np.array` matrix instead:

```
In [28]: iterative_solver(M.A, b, Vinit, kmax, epsmax)
V: (3,) M: (3, 3) b: (3,)
(3,)
np.shape(A): (3,)
...
Out[28]: (array([1., 1., 1.]), 13.856406460551018, 101)
```

edit

---

`np.matrix` is a subclass of `ndarray`.  It defines its own `*` and `**` as matrix operations, as opposed to elementwise.  And it enforces a 2d shape.  If necessary it adds a leading dimension (`numpy` is 'C' order by default)

```
In [150]: M = np.matrix(np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3))
In [151]: v = np.arange(3)
```

Using its own `*`:

```
In [152]: M * v
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [152] in <module>
    M * v
  File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py:218 in __mul__
    return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))
  File <__array_function__ internals>:180 in dot
ValueError: shapes (3,3) and (1,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

The (3,) `v` has been 'promoted' to matrix (1,3).

`matmul/@` is a recent addition (`np.matrix` is old, and on its way out):

```
In [153]: M @ v
Out[153]: matrix([[ 5, 14, 23]])
In [154]: M.dot(v)
Out[154]: matrix([[ 5, 14, 23]])
```

It appears that both of these perform the multiply as though they were `ndarray`, and converts the result to `matrix`.

If both are `np.matrix`:

```
In [155]: V = np.matrix(v)
In [156]: V
Out[156]: matrix([[0, 1, 2]])
In [157]: M * V.T
Out[157]: 
matrix([[ 5],
        [14],
        [23]])
```

`M@V.T` does the same thing.

Comment: Thus when we do matmul in general do we have to make sure that they are both array or both matrix? What is key to looking out for when we perform these matrix multiplication operations to make sure that they are of the same dimensions?

Comment: Also it's weird how this matrix doesn't give me a (3,1) vector does it have something to do with the array.T not working?

Comment: See my edit for more exploration of `np.matrix` product.  Mixing `matrix` and `ndarray` is not a good idea unless you have thoroughly tested things.  I like to say that `np.matrix` was add (years ago) for wayward MATLAB users.  Its use in new code is discouraged.